# CSS align center

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is width 100% and height 100%. Inside I have a 200px x 200px div. I'd like the 200px x 200px to align to the vertical and horizontal center of the outer div. Like in Photoshop when you align to the vertical or horizontal center. I've only been able to align from the edges so far. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your code...

Comment: Try **margin: 0 auto;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin:0 auto;` for set automatic margin according to your page position.

Comment: Note: this will only work as long as a width is set! If the element does not have a set width, it will not be centered.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {display: table;}

#child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Do Note: CSS tables are not the same as HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <div class="two">
   </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.two{
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```